# Increment of a functionnal, derivative function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Consider a path $x:[0;T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that 
$x(0)=x(T)$ and the dynamic is given by $\dot x = f(x)$.

Considering some variations on the intial state $x(0)$ and on the final time $T$, I would like to analyze the equation $x(0)=x(T)$.

The answer is 
$$
\delta x(0) = d x(T) = \delta x(T) + f(x(T))\,d T.
$$
which I don't understand.

---

The increment of $x$ at time $0$ and $T$ wrt $x(0)$ and $T$ is
$$
 \Delta (x(0),\delta x(0),dT) = \Delta (x(T),\delta x(0),dT). \qquad (*)
$$
But $\delta x(0)$ is the linear approximation of $\Delta x(0)$:
$$
\Delta (x(0),\delta x(0),dT) = \delta (x(0),\delta x(0),dT) + H.O.T
$$
so taking only the first order term in $(*)$ 
$$
\delta (x(0),\delta x(0),dT) = \delta (x(T),\delta x(0),dT)
$$
i.e.
$$
\underbrace{\delta (x(0),\delta x(0))}_{\delta x(0)}  =^? \delta (x(T),x(0))+\delta (x(T),dT)=\delta x(T) + dx(T) = \delta x(T) +  f(x(T))dT
$$

but it doesn't yield the result

First, why  $dx(T) = \delta x(T) + f(x(T))\,dT$?

This is taken from the article (see equation (9) ) :

[article][1]
http://sci-hub.io/10.1109/TAC.1984.1103482